# Forced RtL in PySide2 / PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, farsi

I have a QLabel with an unknown text that must be right-to-left, no matter which language is it.  So I wrote this code:

```
def add_label(self):
    text = self.text_input.text() # self.text_input is a QLineEdit
    widget = QLabel(text)
    widget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
    widget.setStyleSheet("color: #000000")
    self.layout.addWidget(widget) # self.layout is a QVBoxLayout
    # I can't setAlignment for self.layout because there is some other QLabels in there that have a LtR alignment.
```

The problem in here is when I write a Persian text in `self.text_input` and run the `add_label` function (via pressing a button) it will automatically change the alignment to RtL and when I call the `widget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)` It will change back to LtR. But I want it to be RtL no matter which language is it.
How to fix this problem?

edit: I added a picture to describe the problem
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to combine the alignment flag with `Qt.AlignAbsolute` so no matter the layout direction the text will always align to the right.

```
widget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignAbsolute)
```